# Пожалуйста объясните, почему получается ввести с клавиатуры именно 7 цифр и после вывод на экран "0"?

Tags: java

**Задача**:

Использовать цикл for, вводить с клавиатуры числа. Если пользователь ввел -1, вывести на экран сумму всех введенных чисел и завершить программу. -1 должно учитываться в сумме.

**Код**:

```
import java.io.*;

public class Solution {
public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception {
    BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    int m = Integer.valueOf(r.readLine());
    int[] a = new int[m];
    int sum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
    {
        Integer.valueOf(r.readLine());
        sum += a[i];
    }

        System.out.println(sum);
  }
}
```

Comment: потому что вы ничего не делаете с результатом `Integer.valueOf(r.readLine());` в цикле.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    try(BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))) {

        List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
        int sum;

        for (; ; ) {
            int number = Integer.valueOf(r.readLine());
            if (number != -1) {
                numbers.add(number);
                continue;
            }
            numbers.add(number);
            sum = numbers.stream().mapToInt(n -> n).sum();
            break;
        }

        System.out.println(sum);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("IOException");
    }
}
```

Так как вам нужен именно цикл for, то есть его интерпретация бесконечности(вам же нужно бесконечно вводить числа). Так как чисел мы не знаем сколько, то используйте List. Считываете, делаете проверку на -1, если верно, то добавить число в лист и пойти на новую итерацию, если нет, то добавляем -1 и считаем сумму с помощью Stream API. Так же используется try с ресурсами,чтобы закрыть ресурсы.

Comment: Зачем использовать `List` и хранить все числа, если требуется только вывести сумму? `number != -1` можно вынести в `for`, что не было нужды в `if`, `continue` и `break`. И даже если вы настаиваете на `continue`, то `numbers.add(number);` можно перенести до `if`-a, чтобы не дублировать код.

Comment: В задании ни где не сказано, сколько чисел будет введено, поэтому я использовал и лист, можно и просто хранить число и его перевычислять(добавлять или отнимать от него). С numbers.add(number) согласен. continue нужен просто, чтобы не использовать else.

Comment: А какая разница сколько чисел? Достаточно хранить сумму (число), изменяя его на каждой итерации. И памяти меньше займёт, и кода меньше. Да и выполняться быстрее будет

Comment: Я это уже понял и выше в сообщении описал "можно и просто хранить число и его перевычислять(добавлять или отнимать от него)"

Answer (score 2):

В вашем коде следует убрать `BufferedReader` и заменить его на `Scaner` потому, что в первом случае возникает риск получить IOException и парсить числа это также не удобно.

Не понятно использование `m` и `a`. Ведь цикл все равно остановится от -1. Их можно заменить на `val`, который будет хранить текущее значение; `quantity` - размер и `res` - результат.

Цикл for в данном случае вообще бесполезен и будет практичнее заменить на do - while.

Код:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
int val, quantity = 0, res = 0;

 do {
    System.out.println("Введите число: ");
    val = scan.nextInt();
    quantity++;
    res += val;

 } while (val != -1);

 System.out.println("Сумма "+res + ", количество " + quantity);
```

Также цикл do - while можно заменить циклом for без итерации:

```
for(val = 0; val != -1;){
    System.out.println("Введите число: ");
    val = scan.nextInt();
    quantity++;
    res += val;
 }
```

Comment: Хотя `for` действительно здесь не к месту, но того требует задание. В принципе, если поместить в `for` `val != -1` и `res += val`, то он не так уж и бесполезно будет смотреться

Comment: А зачем вы считаете количество элементов? Ну и "size" - это всё-таки "размер", а не "количество"

Comment: Исправляю свой ответ